# Unable to mount internal hdd - An error occurred while accessing 'Basic data partition'

Tags: mount, partition, hard-disk, disk, automounting

I have 2 disks in my PC, an SSD with my linux system on it and a HDD with windows and some other stuff.  Now I keep getting the following error, which appeared overnight without changing the system, when I'm trying to mount my HDD, after authentication.

[image: authentication screen of the HDD when trying to mount it]

[authentication screen of the HDD when trying to mount it]

> An error occurred while accessing 'Basic data partition', the system responded: An unspecified error has occurred: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken

Output of /proc/partitions before trying to mount it:

```
259        0  976762584 nvme0n1
 259        1     524288 nvme0n1p1
 259        2  958271734 nvme0n1p2
 259        3   17961962 nvme0n1p3
  11        0    1048575 sr0
   7        1          4 loop1
   7        0      66776 loop0
   7        2      93316 loop2
   7        3      56828 loop3
   7        4      93256 loop4
   7        5      56820 loop5
   7        7      33220 loop7
   7        6     168712 loop6
   7        8      44308 loop8
   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1     102400 sda1
   8        2     131072 sda2
   8        3  975613223 sda3
   8        4     912384 sda4
```

Output of cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=DB6E-0849                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=7b598707-9f6b-42f3-846e-71fd01752e84 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=315943cb-caa9-488a-a3e9-308e6218486f swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
```

Output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error
```

Output of sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDS100T3X0C-00SJG0                      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 29B5454C-DA51-8545-8062-20EC370C77CF

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       4096    1052671    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1052672 1917596140 1916543469 913.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1917596141 1953520064   35923924  17.1G Linux swap


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 65.21 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 91.13 MiB, 95555584 bytes, 186632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 55.5 MiB, 58191872 bytes, 113656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 91.07 MiB, 95494144 bytes, 186512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 55.49 MiB, 58183680 bytes, 113640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 32.44 MiB, 34017280 bytes, 66440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 164.76 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 43.27 MiB, 45371392 bytes, 88616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST31000524AS    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 899D4B03-4C45-4868-A3ED-04525A4A516C

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2      206848     468991     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      468992 1951695437 1951226446 930.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1951696896 1953521663    1824768   891M Windows recovery environment
```

Output sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda

```
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.

With -T permissive:
Short INQUIRY response, skip product id

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Output of sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn:

```
Expanded resource Reserved due to conflict with PCI Bus 0000:00
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: reset failed, giving up
vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
r8168  Copyright (C) 2021 Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
 This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details, please see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 
 This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 
[drm] dce110_link_encoder_construct: Failed to get encoder_cap_info from VBIOS with error code 4!
[drm] dce110_link_encoder_construct: Failed to get encoder_cap_info from VBIOS with error code 4!
hid-generic 0003:1532:0531.0008: No inputs registered, leaving
thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
amdgpu: SRAT table not found
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
ACPI: \: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x1001)
usb 1-5: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
usb 1-5: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
kauditd_printk_skb: 51 callbacks suppressed
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
kauditd_printk_skb: 13 callbacks suppressed
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: reset failed, giving up
ata2.00: disabled
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
program smartctl is using a deprecated SCSI ioctl, please convert it to SG_IO
ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 0, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468994 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 1, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468996 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 2, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468998 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 3, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1951695232 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1951695232 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 975613120, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1951695234 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 975613121, async page read
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1951695236 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 975613122, async page read
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 975613123, async page read
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` and `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Comment: i added it at the end

Comment: Your drive is dead.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drive is most likely dead:

```
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata2: reset failed, giving up

blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 468992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 0, async page read
```

and smartctl not being able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your hard drive is dead.